# PHP foreach: splitting the loop into two parts

Tags: php, foreach

I want to split the loop into two, but I can't figure it out!

I want to loop three items from the array first, and then displaying the remaining items like this,

```
01 Home
02 Portfolio
03 Blog

{my website logo}

04 About
05 Contact
06 Feed
```

This is code where I am stuck in,

```
<?php
    $index = 0;

    foreach($items as $item) 
    {

    ?>
    <li>0<?php echo $index+1;?><a href="#"><?php echo $item['name'];?></a></li>
    <?php   
    $index ++;
    }

?>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: instead of `0<?php echo $index+1;?>` you could do a `printf("%02s", $index+1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($items as $index => $item){
    echo /*<li>*/;
    if ($index == 2){
        echo /*logo*/;
    }
}
```

Do you need something like that?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) is what you are looking for?

```
foreach (array_slice($items, 0, 3) as $item) {
    // print item
}

// display logo

foreach (array_slice($items, 2, 3) as $item) {
    // print item
}
```

Comment: Oops, that second one should probably be a 3 and not a 2...
array_slices($items, 3)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the loop all together and using array_slice with implode()

```
$first_three = array_slice($items, 0, 3); 

print implode("\n", $first_three);
print "LOGO";
print implode("\n", $items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just create 2 for loops

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
?>
  <li>0<?php echo $i+1;?><a href="#"><?php echo $items[$i]['name'];?></a></li>
<?php 
}
?>

// display logo

<?php
for ($i=3; $i<count($items); $i++) {
?>
  <li>0<?php echo $i+1;?><a href="#"><?php echo $items[$i]['name'];?></a></li>
<?php 
}
?>
```